# maven-shade-plugin ConnectException: Connection refused for getting java.sun.com DTD (processed by XMLAppendingTransformer for building Apache CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, maven, cxf, dtd

I have tried to build an old version of Apache CXF, because in our legacy project we are using version Apache CXF 2.2.2, but I get this error when building the full library (with Maven 3.2.5):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.2:shade (default)
on project cxf-bundle: Error creating shaded jar. Connection refused: connect
```

By looking in the stack-trace, I've noticed this:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer.processResource(XmlAppendingTransformer.java:61)
```

and also:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
```

Here is the full stack-trace:

```
mvn -e -Pfastinstall,everything
................................................
................................................

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.2:shade (default) on project cxf-bundle: Error creating shaded jar. Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.2:shade (default) on project cxf-bundle: Error creating shaded jar.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:852)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:793)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:718)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1041)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1193)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:453)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:770)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer.processResource(XmlAppendingTransformer.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.resourceTransformed(DefaultShader.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shade(DefaultShader.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:361)
    ... 21 more
```

Because it is mentioning an **XmlAppendingTransformer** and **XMLEntityManager.*startDTDEntity***, then I imagine that it's related to some DTD reference which is no longer valid, such as the one which appears in **META-INF/cxf/extensions.xml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
```

But how can I fix this?

I am running Maven behind a corporate http proxy, and I already configured the proxy in my *settings.xml* but I still get the "Cannot connect" error.

I have also tried with:

```
mvn -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myport -Dhttp.proxyUser=myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword -Pfastinstall,everything
```

but then I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd
```

How can I skip the checking of the DTD by the XMLAppendingTransformer ?

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging around, I have found that **maven-shade-plugin** has an option to ***ignoreDtd*** (which is actually even enabled by default), but it was only introduced in version 1.3.1, whereas Apache CXF 2.2.2 is using maven-shade-plugin version 1.2:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>
```

So my solution was to upgrade the maven-shade-plugin to version 1.3.1 inside the main *pom.xml*:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
```

But then I started getting another error, which is of a very different nature,  so I documented it here:

[An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1:shade: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382445/an-api-incompatibility-was-encountered-while-executing-org-apache-maven-plugins/)