# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1:shade: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null

Tags: java, maven, cxf, maven-shade-plugin

While trying to build an old version of Apache CXF 2.2.2, I kept getting an error produced by an **XmlAppendingTransformer** used by the **maven-shade-plugin**: unable to connect to get the DTD for http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd (referenced by the file **META-INF/cxf/extensions.xml**)

I have tried to fix this problem by using the ***ignoreDtd*** option provided by maven-shade-plugin starting with version 1.3.1.

But now I am getting another more weird error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1:shade (default) on project cxf-bundle: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1:shade failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1:shade: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.3.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/1.3.1/maven-shade-plugin-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/postese/libraries/apache-cxf-2.2.2-patched-src/buildtools/target/cxf-buildtools-2.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/pmd/pmd/4.2/pmd-4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6/ant-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/postese/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.1/maven-dependency-tree-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.2.2, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Which library or plugin is causing the "API incompatibility" ?

Comment: Is there any good reason why are you using such ancient version of [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) ?

Comment: The reason is because we are using Alfresco 3.4, which is using CXF 2.2.2, which we needed to patch. So I had to compile the sources of CXF 2.2.2 with minimal changes. And the pom.xml of CXF 2.2.2 is using maven-shade-plugin 1.2. In the end I had to upgrade at least the maven-shade-plugin, to the minimal version which works, and that is 1.3.1 :)

Comment: And I know, Alfresco 3.4 is also extremely ancient, but a migration of our project to a newer Alfresco version requires a lot of work. (We have started doing it, but we still need new features to work, such as calling some web services with Apache CXF, and we need them long before finishing the Alfresco upgrade..)

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of digging and trying to eliminate one-by-one the **ResourceTransformers** used by the **maven-shade-plugin**, I have found the culprit:

Apparently now the problem was not caused by the XmlAppendingTransformer, but there are two ResourceTransformers defined by Apache CXF:

```
apache-cxf-2.2.2-patched-src\buildtools\src\main\java\org\apache\cxf\maven:

CXFAllTransformer.java
PluginTransformer.java
```

The two transformers as they were defined in CXF 2.2.2 **are not compatible with** the new **ResourceTransformer interface** defined in maven-shade-plugin **version 1.3.1**, because this new method is missing:

```
public void processResource(String resource, InputStream is, List relocators) throws IOException {
```

They have been "fixed" in CXF 2.2.12, where they include this method.

So my "fix" was to copy the source code of these 2 transformers from the source code of CXF 2.2.12 into the "patched" source code of CXF 2.2.2.